# Netmiko ssh with threadpool

Tags: python, ssh, threadpool, cisco

I have the following portion of python code:
that reads a list of IP addresses from an input file then establishes an ssh connection to send CISCO IOS commands with Netmiko library

```
with open(args.csv, 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for device_row in reader:
        try:
            ssh_session = ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios',
                    ip=device_row['Host'],
                    username=ssh_username, password=ssh_password)
            print '********* {0} *********'.format(device_row['Host'
                    ])

        # Specify your commands here, you can add more commands just follow the same syntax
             print ssh_session.send_command('show running-config | i hostname')

        except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
    print ('{0}'.format(device_row['Host']),"Authenticaiton Problem!")
            pass
```

I want to use thread pool to use this against thousands of devices..

Answer (score 0):

Look at Nornir which has threading support built-in and has plugins that support Netmiko.